# Trading security and tax

Tags: taxes, canada, trading, capital-gain

According to GAAP:

If I buy 1000 shares of security A for 50$.

Then later, I sell 1000 shares of security A for 150$.

At the same moment I buy 1000 shares of security B for 150$.

For tax purpose what is my income?

Is it =>

(1000) * (150-50) - (1000) * (150) = -50K

Or the security B buy is not an expense, so it's would only =>

(1000) * (150-50) = 100K

Comment: What country are you in? Tax laws vary widely. Welcome to Money.SE

Comment: I live in Canada.

Comment: Investment is not an expense.

Comment: Since you are in Canada, you'll want to know that capital gains (the proceeds from selling an investment for a higher price than you bought it for) are typically taxed more favorably than regular income.

Comment: @littleadv Yes it is.  Stick to taxes.  Your financial accounting skills leave much to be desired.

Comment: @quantycuenta Investment produces asset, it is not an expense. Don't argue just for the sake of it, please. The question was about taxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$100k would be your profit and income (sometimes this profit or capital gains may be discounted if held for a certain period). Stock B is not an expense it is an asset. When you sell it you would count the profit or loss from it as your income.

Expenses would include any brokerage you paid to buy and sell the shares.

Comment: We would usually say $100k profit and 50% of that is capital gains.  It's not reported as income (usually), but is treated differently in your taxes.  In his case, it's only $50k in taxable income.

Comment: @brian - In most countries the 50% discount (or other discount) on capital gains usually applies to longer-term gains, usually for assets held for more than 12 months, or else there is no discount. And don't these gains (discounted or not) then get added to your other taxable income so that you pay tax on them based on your tax bracket. So in the end it does get included as part of your income. This is how it is worked out in Australia. Also, there was no country tag when I answered this question.

Comment: In Canada there is no short/long term capital gains.  It's all capital gains and 50% of it is included in your income.  There's a distinction in Canada between the words income, dividends, and capital gains as they're all taxed differently.

Comment: @brian - you just said it yourself, after the discount is applied, the remaining 50% "is included in your income." Dividends and capital gains may have some preferential treatment applied to them (whether a discount, tax credits or something else), but once this is done they are added to ones other taxable income on which tax will be payable on.

Comment: The tax law has different meanings for "capital gains" and "income".  I don't care what people call it as long as they understand the difference.  I've already seen a wrong answer here when someone mixed them up.

Comment: How is tax paid on capital gains?

Comment: It depends on many factors that apply to cap gains and not income or dividends.  If you're really interested, ask a new question and I'll do my best. Search T4037, ITA section 39, and also IT-479 for Canada, maybe even T123.

Comment: Do you file separately for CG or does it get included when you file you income taxes? If it is the later then it is simply added to your taxable income. Simple as that.